# Arduino Ethernet Shield e PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web, arduino

Olá
Eu estou desenvolvendo um código para arduino + ethernet que faz o acionamento de métodos GET (PHP), e o PHP faz o envio dos dados recebidos do arduino para o MySQL.

O código em php funciona perfeitamente, o ethernet consegue se conectar ao servidor pela porta '8095' mas não consegue acionar os parâmetros GET . Eu não sei bem se o problema está no código, ou em aguma área relacionada com a rede.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
byte ip[] = {192,168,1,60};                         //IP DO ARDUINO (WEB CLIENT)
byte servidor[] = {192,168,1,8};                   //IP DO SERVIDOR 

EthernetClient cliente;

void setup() {   
            Serial.begin(9600);  
            Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
         }

void loop() {

 if (cliente.connect(servidor, 8095))  //Se o arduino se conectar ao servidor
{
     cliente.print("GET /programas/Query.php?a=2"); //Envia  $_GET['a'] = 2;
     cliente.print(" HTTP/1.1");
     cliente.stop();
     Serial.println("Informação enviada com sucesso!"); 
} 
else {Serial.println("Falha na conexão");}
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, não poste seus códigos em forma de imagem; o [pt.so] possui suporte a eles tanto na pergunta quanto na resposta, então edite sua pergunta de acordo. Segundo, não seria falta de cabeçalhos HTTP? Ou só da quebra de linha indicando que todos os cabeçalhos foram enviados.

Comment: Já tentei mas infelizmente não funcionou, o Arduino consegue se conectar ao webserver (Apache) mas não consegue executar os parâmetros GET hospedados neste servidor.

Comment: Tem algum retorno do servidor após a requisição?

Comment: Não, nada acontece...
Caso o código funcionasse o PHP enviaria o valor '2' para uma tabela em um banco de dados MySQL, mas isso não acontece.

Já tentei acionar os pelo navegador e funcionou, só não funciona mesmo pelo arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta para esse problema no stackoverflow(Inglês) o problema estava na extrutura HTTP1.1

Abaixo está a extrutura correcta.

```
"GET /programas/Query.php?a=2\r\nHost: 192.168.1.8\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra duvida por esse mesmo código como faço para retornar e imprimir o que foi processado no lado servidor no monitor serial?